# Solving differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

There is a cylindrical container whose height is 10 meters and whose base radius is 1 meter. The bottom of the container has a hole, and water leaks out at a rate (meter cube per min) equal to the height of the water in the container. A pump is turned on to fill the container with water. The rate (meter cubes per min) at which water is pumped into the container t mins after pump is turned on is t divided by volume of water in container at time t. If height of water in container at t=0 is 1 meter, find a formula for volume of water in container at time t.

I broke it down into three parts, but not sure whether my differential equation is correct as it looks odd. Can somebody help me check if this is the right equation and whether my final answer is correct?

The equation I obtained: dv/dt = V + t/V - V/pi

The ans I obtained: V = sqrt(t/[2(1-(1/pi))])+ 2.29

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please use mathjax to type formulas. Also, I dont see where the first $V$ of the right hand side of your ODE is coming from.

Comment: V comes from the water that is already present in the container at t=0 where the height is 1 meter. I am actually not very sure whether I need to include the initial volume in the differential equation. Do I just remove it?